# How to react to sub events from onbeforeunload?

Tags: javascript, html

I noticed that the event `onbeforeunload` is able to distinguish between different user actions, e.g. whether the user pressed on a link on the page, the user tried to close the page, the user wanted to go one page back etc.

For example if a user clicks on a link, then a confirm box with the text "*Are you sure that you want to close the page?*" prompts, but if the user presses `F5` to refresh the page, then the text of the box is "*Are you sure that you want to refresh the page?*".

Is it possible to distinguish the different sub events from onbeforeunload and react to it?

What I try is to change the background-color of my page to red if the user tries to leave the page, and to orange if he tries to refresh the page, thats just a simple test action for better understanding.

**NOTE**: I translated the text from the prompt from German to English, so the text could be different.

**SIDE QUESTION**: Why does the confirm box appears twice if i click on the link   and press "Leave page" if i run this code on my local webserver, but not if i run it on stackoverflow?

```js
function ask()
{
  return "Are you sure?";
  
  //How can i find out what the user actually tried? 
  //e.g. did he tried to refresh the page? Or did he tried to close it?
  //PSEUDO CODE:
  //  if (user_tried_reload) { alert("RELOAD"); }
  //  else if (user_tried_close) { alert ("CLOSE"); }
}
```

```html
<body onbeforeunload="return ask()">
    <h1>onbeforeunload Test</h1>
    <a href="http://www.google.de">Google</a>
</body>
```

**USAGE**: Press on "*Run code snippet*" and then whether click on the link or try to refresh the page.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the code fires twice is because the "Leave Page" button re-triggers the unload event.

What I suggest you do is catch the F5 keypress event and do your own message:

```
document.onkeydown = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    if (evt.keyCode == 116) {
        ask('reload');
    }
};
```

In your ask() function, I'd so something like this:

```
var howmanytimes = 0;
function ask(action)
{
  howmanytimes++;

  //PSEUDO CODE:
  if (howmanytimes == 1) {
     if (action == 'reload') { alert("RELOAD"); }
     else { alert ("CLOSE"); }
  } else { howmanytimes == 0 };
}
```

This code is untested and I don't have access to jsfiddle from where I am, hope this points you in the right direction (and that I understood the question correctly in the first place!)

Comment: page can be refreshed by clicking on the refresh icon in the browser, ctrl + r, F5

Comment: Thx. But if the user presses the reload button on the browser, then it is still recognized as CLOSE

Comment: If you catch F5 (and remember Ctrl+R), check event.ClientY is < 0 (close button clicked) instead of just assuming closed, then you'll know refresh was clicked. Makes sense?